¿Por que COUNT DISTINCT con JOIN y GROUP BY no devuelve cero?
Contexto

El sistema necesita calcular la cantidad total de ofertas.
La consulta es modificada dinámicamente dependiendo de los filtros aplicados.
Uno de los filtros que puede ser aplicado es buscar por código de producto (WHERE OP.item_id = X).
El problema se presenta (independientemente de si se filtra por código de producto) cuando se necesita obtener el total de ofertas.

Problema
Tengo las siguientes tablas:
CREATE TABLE offers (
  offer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(250)
);

CREATE TABLE offers_products (
  offer_id INT,
  item_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(offer_id, item_id),
  INDEX (offer_id),
  INDEX (item_id)
);

Ambas están vacías.
Si realizo esta consulta:
SELECT COUNT(O.offer_id) AS total
FROM offers AS O;

Obtengo:
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+

Ahora, si realizo la siguiente consulta:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT O.offer_id) AS total
FROM offers AS O
    LEFT JOIN offers_products AS OP
        ON O.offer_id = OP.offer_id
GROUP BY O.offer_id;

Obtengo:
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Probe con:
IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT O.offer_id), 0) AS total
COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT O.offer_id), 0) AS total

Ninguna funciona.
¿Por que sucede esto?
Demo
Nota:
Se que en este caso no tiene sentido agregar DISTINCT ya que estoy aplicando GROUP BY sobre la misma columna a contar, pero si lo saco pasa lo mismo.

¿Mismo caso? (aunque estaría bueno contar con una respuesta también en español)

@padaleiana, gracias! diría que sí. Lástima que no hay referencia a nada que respalde lo argumentado.

La función COUNT retorna NULL cuando no hay datos que contar. Ahora si inserta algún dato si devuelve 1 o 2 descuerdo al dato insertado:
INSERT INTO offers(name) value ("Comida");
INSERT INTO offers(name) value ("Arepa");

@DABL03 no es eso... sino la primer consulta no debería devolver cero.

Pero si ambas tablas están vacías y cuentas, obviamente vas a obtener cero. No entiendo que intentas lograr.

@ErnestoRincon la segunda no devuelve un registro con el total en cero, sino que directamente no devuelve nada

Intentaste realizar la consulta sin usar el GROUP BY como comentan en la publicación que te adjunto @padaleiana ?

@ErnestoRincon, si y funciona. Es más, en el caso particular que presento con sacar el GROUP BY funciona. A mi me gustaría saber el "porque... ". Pero ojo que el caso podría ser aplicando GROUP BY en otra columna, por lo que no se podría sacar.

La razón es que cuando no tiene registros, la cláusula GROUP BY no tiene nada por lo que agrupar, y luego no puede darle ninguna salida.

Son dos consultas totalmente distintas en lo que hacen, la primera, cuenta ocurrencias de offer_id distintas en la tabla, no hay filas, el count es 0. La otra genera grupos por offer_id y cuenta las cantidades de cada grupo, acá no hay count que valga por que antes, no existen los grupos al no haber filas. Creo que este último concepto se entendería mejor expresando la segunda consulta, como debiera ser en realidad:
SELECT  O.offer_id,
        COUNT(1) AS total
        FROM offers AS O
             LEFT JOIN offers_products AS OP
             ON O.offer_id = OP.offer_id
        GROUP BY O.offer_id;

El problema acá se ve más claramente, no es que count funcione distinto, es que no hay grupos dónde aplicar el count

A ver si entendí, vos decis que antes de que el motor intente realizar el COUNT ya no hay nada, por ende directamente el motor ni lo intenta. Correcto? Básicamente el motor descarta estas instrucciones cuando no hay grupos sobre cual aplicarlas, no así cuando no hay registros.

¿Por que diría que es correcto que esto si funcione? La duda es real, te soy sincero quiero entenderlo.

Exacto, no hay grupo donde "aplicar" count o cualquier otra función, para ser  exactos con la segunda consulta, la primera debiera ser así: SELECT O.offer_id, COUNT(1) AS total FROM offers AS O GROUP BY O.offer_id

Correcto. Pero con el outer join debe ser COUNT(OP.offer_id) para considerar offers sin products. Si esos no existen, hay que usar un inner join en vez.

@PatricioMoracho encontré este artículo donde enumeran los distintos casos donde una consulta puede devuelve un set vacío.
